# remove all text from string after given word in php

Tags: php

i've a query string like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `backplanechanneldecoder` WHERE  Pair = '3' LIMIT 25,25
```

and i want to remove all the text which comes after LIMIT.

Note: This string is generated dynamically from another code on which I've no control that's why I've to remove part of string from my end.

Comment: *"i've a string like this"* - Looks more like a "query" to me. You'll need to explain your question, and why you're doing this.

Comment: Er.... Just remove `LIMIT 25,25` ? What is the difficult in that?

Comment: this query was generating dynamically that;s why i cant just simply remove it

Comment: So, remove the part that is generating it.

Comment: I'd say that: So, remove the part that is generating it.²

Comment: @Fred-ii- You just opened a whole new world for him.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes it is a query but generation dynamically.. i want to fetch all record by removing limit

Comment: or set the limit to 0 and LEN(' of the text')

Comment: @Loko Isn't it *wonderful?!* ;-)

Comment: try this:-<?php
$newstring = explode('LIMIT',$string);
$newstring1 = $newstring[0];
print_r($newstring1);
?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use str_pos to find the word LIMIT and then strip after that using substr

```
$string = 'SELECT * FROM `backplanechanneldecoder` WHERE  Pair = 3 LIMIT 25,25';
$limit_pos = strpos($string, 'LIMIT');
$string = substr($string, 0, $limit_pos);
echo $string;
```